# Automated restart problems after Windows10 Update

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, reboot

I have a machine running Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB and it is supposed to run unattended for long stretches of time (think months or longer). It is running without periphery, so I can only access it remote desktop.

As the machine is connected to the internet, it every so often receives Windows updates (which is not a bad thing per se, IMO). Unfortunately, sometimes when it receives an update, the subsequent auto-reboot fails and I have to manually cycle the power to restart it. After such a cold reset, everything seems to be fine and the update is listed as successfully installed. Normal reboots via the start menu are no problem at all, just the update-related ones seem to be (and I don't know yet if that's the case always or if some updates do run through and some fail sporadically)

Windows updates are already set to "defer feature updates", but I am not sure how to reliably disable further updates. Also, as I said, I do not know if this would be the most sensible thing to do, security-wise.

So I don't mind the update and restart process itself, as the computer is configured to automagically resume its tasks after any kind of restart. But these manual power cyclings are a bit of a pain in the... rear end, so I'd be grateful for any hints to what I can do to diagnose and/or remedy the cause of this problem?

Comment: We have machines at customers that restart overnight (3:00am) without issue. Update the BIOS, all other drivers, do a manual Windows 10 Enterprise update, restart and test. If that does not work, repair the operating system with the Enterprise DVD.

Comment: Windows shouldn’t run into a problem with automatic reboots.  Any machine I have automatically reboots without any issues.  You should diagnose those issues.  You didn’t provide any details on the problems you do face.  You can [exit] your question to provide the necessary information required to answer your question

Comment: A long-running computer shouldn't really do updates if you want it really stable, especially if it's mostly dedicated to known applications. It's also a good idea to schedule a reboot at least every week to restart with clean memory, as artifacts may accumulate in Windows over time.

Comment: @Ramhound: Unfortunately, that's about all information I have (there is some more detail now in the edited original post), that's why I was asking for directions on how to diagnose the problem, too. Normal resets are no problem, just the ones triggered by updates.